# Register-ObjectEvent cmdlet not working properly on Powershell but working on ISE

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am working on a Powershell Script to monitor a folder and when a new item is created the script needs to copy that file to another folder.

The issue I'm experiencing is that when I execute it in Powershell ISE it works perfectly but when executing it on Powershell it only works for the period of time that Powershell window is open (> 1 second).

I tried putting the sleep command at the end, and found that only when the script got ended the action is taken, in this case, when I press CTRL+C to stop the script in Powershell, the actions that should have been taken when I created the items are executed all together.

Don't know if I am doing something wrong or just misunderstanding something.

Here is the script i am using to test it:

```
$Watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$Watcher.path = "\\192.168.5.127\data\TestWatcher"
$Destination = "C:\TestWatcher"
$Watcher | Get-Member -MemberType Event
$Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$action = {
    $path = $event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $name = $event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changetype = $event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    Write-Host "File $name at path $path was $changetype at $(get-date)"
    Copy-Item $Watcher.path $Destination
}

Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher 'Created' -Action $action
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Best Regards,

Comment: Try using `-NoExit` when creating the parent process. `powershell.exe -File path.ps1 -NoExit`

Comment: Hello Santiago,

I have tried it with Windows Run putting these "powershell.exe -File path.ps1 -NoExit" but had the same result, the powershell window just opens for a moment and closes back

Comment: The only thing i been able to is to put a
```
while ($true){
}
```
at the end of the script. This keeps the powershell window open and makes the script work, if someone have an idea for a better option i would be glad, i don't think is the best way to have this window in the screen and if someone closes it the script would terminate. Tried also the option -WindowStyle Hidden but didn't worked.

Comment: Using the while described below and the option -WindowStyle hidden when calling the script makes the script to keep executed in the background, i think for now this will work. But will appreciate if someone have any idea that fits better.

Comment: Wihtout having experiences with this particular topic ... according to this blog  post the solution with `while($true)` seems to be a valid solution  [Monitoring Folders for File Changes](https://powershell.one/tricks/filesystem/filesystemwatcher)

Comment: `while($true)` will burn cpu cycles, maybe try `wait-event 'forever'` at the end

Comment: also note that the reason it works in the ISE is because the environment isn't disposed, so the object that the event handler is attached to is never given over to the garbage handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Gregor y](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4496560/gregor-y) provided the crucial hint in a comment:

To **ensure that your script keeps processing events indefinitely**, you can **use a [`Wait-Event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/wait-event) call at the end of your script to *indefinitely* wait for events that will never arrive**, which keeps your script running, but - unlike `Start-Sleep` - does *not* block processing of events via the script block passed to [`Register-ObjectEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent)'s `-Action` parameter:

```bash
$Watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$Watcher.path = "\\192.168.5.127\data\TestWatcher"
$Destination = "C:\TestWatcher"
$Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$action = {
    $path = $event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $name = $event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changetype = $event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    Write-Host "File $name at path $path was $changetype at $(get-date)"
    Copy-Item $Watcher.path $Destination
}

# Register the event with a self-chosen name passed to -SourceIdentifier
# and an -Action script block.
$eventJob = 
  Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher Created -SourceIdentifier FileWatcher -Action $action

# Now wait indefinitely for an event with the same source identifier to arrive.
# NONE will ever arrive, because the events are handled via the -Action script block.
# However, the call will prevent your script from exiting, without
# blocking the processing of events in the -Action script block.
# Use Ctrl-C to exit the script; the `finally` clause ensures cleanup.
try {
  Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier FileWatcher
} 
finally {
  # Clean up: Remove the event job, which also unregisters the event.
  $eventJob | Remove-Job -Force 
}
```

---

**Alternatively, make do *without* an `-Action` script block and process events in a `Wait-Event` loop**:

```bash
$Watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$Watcher.path = "\\192.168.5.127\data\TestWatcher"
$Destination = "C:\TestWatcher"
$Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

# Register the event with a self-chosen name passed to -SourceIdentifier
# but WITHOUT an -Action script block.
Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher 'Created' -SourceIdentifier FileWatcher

# Now use Wait-Event with the chosen source identifier to
# to indefinitely receive and then process the events as they 
# become available.
try {
  while ($event = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier FileWatcher) {
    $path = $event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $name = $event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changetype = $event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    Write-Host "File $name at path $path was $changetype at $(Get-Date)"
    Copy-Item $Watcher.path $Destination
    $event | Remove-Event # Note: Events must be manually removed.
  }
}
finally {
  # Clean up.
  Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FileWatcher
}
```

---

**Alternative with *event-polling loop* that permits *foreground activity*:**

You can adapt the above to use a *polling* approach, by using an *unconditional* infinite loop, and replacing `Wait-Event` with a [`Get-Event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-event) call inside the loop body, followed by short sleep intervals (via [`Start-Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep)), which allows you to perform *foreground activities* while no events are being received:

```bash
$Watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$Watcher.path = "\\192.168.5.127\data\TestWatcher"
$Destination = "C:\TestWatcher"
$Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

# Register the event with a self-chosen name passed to -SourceIdentifier
# but WITHOUT an -Action script block.
Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher 'Created' -SourceIdentifier FileWatcher

# Now enter an infinite loop that uses Get-Event to poll for
# available events and processes them.
# If none are available, foreground activity can be performed
# (which should be short-lived, otherwise event retrieval is blocked).
try {
  while ($true) {
    if ($event = Get-Event | Where-Object SourceIdentifier -eq FileWatcher) {
      $path = $event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
      $name = $event.SourceEventArgs.Name
      $changetype = $event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
      Write-Host "File $name at path $path was $changetype at $(Get-Date)"
      Copy-Item $Watcher.path $Destination
      $event | Remove-Event # Note: Events must be manually removed.
    } else { # No event available.
      # Perform (short-lived) foreground activities here.
      Write-Host -NoNewline .
      Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500 # Sleep a little, to avoid a tight loop.
    }
  }
}
finally {
  # Clean up.
  Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FileWatcher
}
```

Note:

- Due to a **bug** present up to at least PowerShell v7.3.x, `Get-Event` doesn't work with the `-SourceIdentifier` parameter, hence the `Get-Event | Where-Object SourceIdentifier -eq FileWatcher` workaround above.

  - See [GitHub issue #11705](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11705).